# Is there a good report server engine for ASP.NET similar to Jasper Reports?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

Is there a good web report server engine for ASP.NET similar to Jasper Reports?

**I need to**
- Schedule reports
- Let clients design reports
- Let clients design querys
- Export reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Reporting Services comes out of the box with SQL Server. Does all the things you mention here.